# Ajax/Json request to Controller in Play1.2.7 not working specifying content type

Tags: json, playframework-1.x

I have this js code

```
function sendJSon(){
    var user = {"user_name" : $("#my_input_field").val()};

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:9000/myAction',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        success: function(result) {
            $("#my_res_div").html(result);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

which works perfectly when passed to the application and then goes on success as it was meant to.
But I reached this goal after many tries because at the beginning (browsing this site) I found answers which suggested to specify also content type (application/json or text/javascript) and data type (json) for JSon requests.

I wonder why I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9000/myAction. Invalid HTTP status code 404` if I specify either content or data types.
This the route line in route file

```
POST    /myAction                           Application.jsonRequest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're quoting basically means the response to the POST request is a 404 status, which is not an expected value for a POST request (you're sending content, it is illogical for the server to say it can't find that content).

Specifying the `dataType` field for `$.ajax` is generally not needed, because it will try to figure it out itself. However, this field should not cause a problem, because it is about parsing the response data, which only happens after the response is received, and the error code indicates a bad response in the first place (meaning it never goes to parsing).

The `contentType` field for `$.ajax` is more important for a request. It is a two part string, specifying the type of content being sent and the character set being used to encode the content. So the problem with setting it to either of the values you name is that there is that the character encoding is missing. Another problem is that you're specifying a datatype while at the same time not providing your data in that format. You're explicitly stringifying your content, which means it won't be JSON data.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  You taught me interesting things and pointed out a big mistake/misunderstanding of mine.